# Alternative to eglSwapBuffers before API-9

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I compiled the JNI sample `hello-gl2` from the NDK-r8 on my android 2.2 phone.
I was wondering if I could modify it and call `eglSwapBuffers`.
Then, I noticed that this function is not available before API-9.
So I decided to cross-compile `freeglut` because `EGL/egl.h` is not available before API-9.
Is there an alternative to `eglSwapBuffers` before API-9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On lower API you must create and call SwapBuffers on GL context from Java. GLSurfaceView does this for you in easy way, but you can re-implement it's functionality if you wish.

There is no other official way how to do it.